# What is the purpose of "ts & 0xffff0000"?

Tags: c, network-programming, operators

I'm working on a real time protocol that adding the timestamp for each transmitted packet and I don't understand what the lines of code mean. Thanks for help.

```
// ts for timestamp
unsigned int ts;


if(ts & 0xffff0000){
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the fact they're using binary-and (`&`), the intent seems to be to check if any of the 16 high bits are set.

Binary-and examines the bits at each position in both numbers, and if they're both 1, then the result as a 1 bit in that same position.  Otherwise the result has a zero in that position

```
0b 001001001001001001001001001001  (first number, usually a variable)
0b 010101010101010101010101010101  (second number, usually a "mask")
=================================
0b 000001000001000001000001000001  (result)
```

If this is used as the condition of an if-block, such as `if (x & mask)`, then the if-block is entered if `x` has any of the same bits as `mask` set.  For `0xFFFF0000`, the block will be entered if any of the high 16 bits are set.

That is effectively the same as `if (ts > 65535)` (if `int` is 32bit or less), but apparently the intent is to deal with bits, rather than the actual value.

Comment: @mafso: If `int` is 33 bits, then it could hold the value 0x100000000, which fails to match the mask, but is definitely `>65535`. I feel like you might have misunderstood the sentence in the answer though.

Answer (score 4):

`0xffff0000` serves as a bit mask here.

`ts & 0xffff0000` satisfies as a condition when some bit in the first 16 bits of `ts` is 1. Put another way, when `ts >= 2^16`.

Answer (score 1):

This IF loop **checks if any of upper 16 bits** of `ts` is **high**. If yes, then loop is executed.

The IF loop is executed only if `ts >= 0x00010000`.

Comment: oops, the ts >= 0xFFFF0000 should be ts >= 0x0000ffff

Answer (score 0):

An intuitive way to understand this.

```
    **** **** **** **** //the first 16bits of ts
&   1111 1111 1111 1111 //the first 16bits of 0xffff 0000
```

If one of the first 16bits of ts is set, then the result above won't be zero.
If they are all 0, the result above will be `0000 0000 0000 0000`

For the last 16bits of ts, no matter what happens to these bits, the result of Binary-and will be 0.

```
    **** **** **** ****
&   0000 0000 0000 0000
   =0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So if the first 16 bits of ts have one 1 bit ==>  `ts&0xffff0000` > 0 (which means `ts>=0b 10000 0000 0000 0000`(i.e., 2^16)), el se `ts&0xffff0000 == 0`.

Always, we also use this `ts&1` to test whether ts is an odd number.